# Return a reference by a class function and return a whole object in c++?

Tags: c++, function, class, object, reference

Operator overloading in class CVector:

```
CVector CVector::operator+ (CVector param) {
  CVector temp;
  temp.x = x + param.x;
  temp.y = y + param.y;
  return (temp);
}
```

and in main:

```
CVector a (3,1);
  CVector b (1,2);
  CVector c;
  c = a + b;
```

So an object is passed by value, and then another temp object is being created. I guess b is being passed by value, a is the one calling the + therefore the x and y belong to a and pram.x and param.y to b. temp is returned and the the copy assignment operator delivers temp's values to c?

But what about this:

```
CVector& CVector::operator= (const CVector& param)
{
  x=param.x;
  y=param.y;
  return *this;
}
```

and in main:

```
a=b;
```

Again a is calling the = and b is being passed by reference as const.(in this case does it matter if it was passed by value?) This is where i get confused, x belonging to a is assigned param.x of be. so why isn't this function void, since x and y can be accessed by this function. What does return *this means, i know that this is the address of the object calling the function, so *this would be the function itself, but if we are returning an object we need to assign it it somewhere like the previous c=temp after temp=a+b? 
And what does CVector& even mean, it doesn't look like we are expecting an address of an object of CVector type?

In other words why isn't the function just:

```
void CVector::operator= (const CVector& param)
    {
      x=param.x;
      y=param.y;
    }
```

??

Then there is this code

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;
 class Calc { 
private: 
  int value; 
public: 
  Calc(int value = 0) { this->value = value; } 
  Calc& Add(int x) { value += x; return *this; } 
  Calc& Sub(int x) { value -= x; return *this; } 
  Calc& Mult(int x) { value *= x; return *this; } 
  int GetValue() { return value; } }; 

int main() { 
  Calc cCalc(2); 
  cCalc.Add(5).Sub(3).Mult(4); 
  cout << cCalc.GetValue(); 
  return 0; 
}
```

Now if i removed the & from the functions:

```
  Calc Add(int x) { value += x; return *this; } 
  Calc Sub(int x) { value -= x; return *this; } 
  Calc Mult(int x) { value *= x; return *this; }
```

and used

```
Calc cCalc(2)
cCalc.Add(5);
cCalc.Sub(3);
cCalc.Mult(4);
```

instead of the former, it would produce the same resault.
So why does Calc& returne type allow chaining.

I not only want to know how to program, since object oriented is much writing by a pattern (this is written like this, this is needed if that) opposed to structured programming where you have to use logic, but also to know why is a peace of code defined as it is, and why it isn't as i intuitively think it should be(although i only learn programming for about a year).

Thanks!

Comment: It's so you can chain assignments a = b = c;

Comment: First b gets the values of c then a gets those of be. First b calls the its void operator= function with an argument c, and then a call its void with argument b. Why not?

Comment: Because `a = b = c` is `a = (b = c)`, which, when user defined `operator=` is involved, is `a.operator=( b.operator=( c ) )`.  Which isn't going to work if the return type of `b.operator=( c )` is `void`.  (A more pertinent question is why it returns a non-const reference, rather than a const reference.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> so why isn't this function void, since x and y can be accessed by this function. What does return *this means

Since `operator=()` is declared to return a reference, `return *this;` returns a reference to the current object. This allows us to chain assignment operators. For example,

```
a = b = c;
```

will call `b.operator=(c);` and return a reference to `b`. Then `a` is assigned by a call which is equivalent to `a.operator=(b)`.

Answer (score 1):

First, the usual convention in C++ is to pass class type
arguments as references to const.  There are clearly exceptions
(predicate objects or iterators in the standard library), but in
application level code, passing a class type by reference to
const is ubiquitous enough to justify a comment:

```
Vector
Vector::operator+( Vector const& rhs ) const
{
    //  ...
}
```

Or more likely:

```
Vector
operator+( Vector const& lhs, Vector const& rhs )
{
    Vector results( lhs );
    results += rhs;
    return results;
}
```

Another widespread convention is to make such binary operators
free functions, so that both the left and right arguments ar
treated in the same fashion.  And to implement them in terms of
=, so as to ensure that = and  have the desired
relation.

For operators which modify the left argument, like the
assignment operators, it is on the other hand the convention to
make them members; the `operator=` must in fact be a member.
A free function `Vector& operator+=( Vector& lhs, Vector const&
rhs )` would be legal, but rather unusual.

As for why `operator=` returns `Vector&`: convention.  It most
accurately simulates what the built in operators do:

```
int&
MyClass::funcWithInt( int newValue )
{
    return myInt = newValue;
}
```

is legal (even if many, myself included, would consider it bad
stype), so the same code should be legal with a class type which
overloads operator=.  And of course, the compiler generated
`operator=` will return a reference to const, so there's
a strong argument for doing the same when you write one
yourself.

Comment: The compiler accepts both.  From the human reader point of view, `Vector const&` is preferable, because it is more coherent.

Comment: `Vector const& lhs` is disabling optimizations.  If you need a copy, why not pass by value, and let the compiler move if possible?

Comment: @BenVoigt Because I don't want to confuse my readers.  (And any optimization would only occur if the first argument were a temporary.)